# folding at home client installation w/ origami

Tags: 10.04, command-line

I'm running Lucid Lynx; I downloaded origami and have it installed via sudo command in terminal. The next step is to use origami to do the installation of the f@h client...
When I try the recommended commands for Ubuntu 8.04 and newer, here's what happens:

(my input):

```
  sudo origami install -t 45104 -u pjkaiser
```

(terminal output):

```
  INSTALLING... PLEASE BE PATIENT
  ERROR: STARTUP SCRIPT FAILED TO START!
```

I'm still pretty new to Linux distros, so an help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/origami/+bug/297578

solution (from the above bug report) (Change "USERNAME" to your log in name).

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo origami erase
sudo origami install -t 45104 -u USERNAME -p amd64 -k PASSKEY -b big
sudo /etc/init.d/origami start
```

See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9647467&postcount=1